# Creating DID (Decentralized ID) Document using Form - This is the Document that's tied to a DID

Tags: decentralization, identity, uport

New to working with decentralized identities. I can't find a good resource that takes data elements from a form and makes a DID document. Any direction or link would be appreciated!

I am working with ReactJS and Ethereum/Polygon.

DID's are Decentralized ID's used in decentralized solutions to manage identities. Below are details on DID's from W3:
https://www.w3.org/TR/did-core/

DIDs are unique identifiers for a specific ID and DID documents are the documents tied to the DID's like a key value relationship.

Below is an example DID:
[image]

Below is an example DID Document:

```
{
  "@context": [
    "https://www.w3.org/ns/did/v1",
    "https://w3id.org/security/suites/ed25519-2020/v1"
  ]
  "id": "did:example:123456789abcdefghi",
  "authentication": [{
    
    "id": "did:example:123456789abcdefghi#keys-1",
    "type": "Ed25519VerificationKey2020",
    "controller": "did:example:123456789abcdefghi",
    "publicKeyMultibase": "zH3C2AVvLMv6gmMNam3uVAjZpfkcJCwDwnZn6z3wXmqPV"
  }]
}
```

An ugly way to go about this is to convert table values into a JSON string that looks like a DID document. But I am hoping there's a library that allows me to take table values and automatically generate this DID Document.

Comment: What's a DID document?

Comment: @Ismael Thank you for pointing that out, I added more context to the question.

Comment: I don't get the question. Each did method has it own way to **build** a did document and most of them require read access to the ledger to get the values. The process is called "resolving" and the DID Doc of the did:ethr method is different from the did document of did:indy or did:sov.... here is an example for did:ethr resolver https://github.com/decentralized-identity/ethr-did-resolver that resolve this method https://github.com/decentralized-identity/ethr-did-resolver/blob/master/doc/did-method-spec.md

Comment: "An ugly way to go about this is to convert table values into a JSON" <- that is what i don't get.. because the values should not come from your tables?.. they should be set and extracted as documented in the specification of the did method using decentralized ledger / blockchain / backend